# How I can get the text that I type on google search bar like onpress event by react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

Actually, I want to build something that can catch every keystroke when I want to type on the google search bar. is that possible to build in react native? without my own keyboard. it should get any input from anywhere like a keylogger

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code.

Comment: Please add some more information to your question so that everyone can understand the problem and help you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try listen change event of input
for example:

```js
let input = document.getElementById('myinput');
input.addEventListener('change', e => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    console.log('value',value);
});
```

Comment: I think this is only for a specific input field but I I want something like a keylogger that catches every keystroke

Comment: oww I get it. Then no idea sorry.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your input to change as you type then you should follow something like this:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      onChangeText={text => setInput(text)}
      value={input}
      placeholder="input some text"
      placeholderTextColor="gray"
    />
```

This will make it so every keystroke will update the `input` as well as deleting what was once written on it.

You should also have a cleaner logic in your `submit` button or `search` button to reset the input to an empty string again `''` so you are not left with the previous text and having to delete ir every time. Something like this:

```
onPress={() => {
//your submit trigger
setInput('');
}}
```